# Reporting during long running async function using set interval in node.js (backend service)

Tags: node.js, async-await, setinterval

I need to report the status of a long running operation in node.js. The basic use case is outlined in the code below. awaiting the longProcess method I know will act synchronously to the caller, but I must await the method in my code. Should I handle this within the longProcess method? Not sure how to address this issue.

```
function sleep (ms: number) {
  new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

let processedCount = 0;

async function longProcess() {
  // really long operation
  while (true) {
    processedCount++;
    await sleep(1000); // simulate long process
    if (processedCount === 10) // just to end the test somehow
      break;
  }
}

async function report() {
  console.log(processedCount);
}

async function main() {
  const id = setInterval(report, 500);
  await longProcess();
  clearInterval(id);
}

main().then(() => console.log("Done"));
```

The sleep method is just for demonstration purposes to simulate a long running operation. 'longProcess' performs complex and time intensive processing. It calls a callback passed in to report back a processed count the caller. The class that contains the calling method (and the callback), also has a report method that I would like to call at regular intervals. And I need to be able to create a unit test for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sleep function is not returning the promise you are creating. You are calling await on the value returned from the function, which in this case is undefined so it doesn't actually wait at all.

```
function sleep (ms: number) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

Comment: The sleep method is just for testing purposes to simulate a long running operation.  'longProcess' performs complex and time intensive processing.  It calls a callback passed in to report back a processed count the caller.  The class that contains the calling method (and the callback), also has a report method that I would like to call at regular intervals.  And I need to be able to create a unit test for this.  I will update the question with this infor.

Comment: You are starting a promise several times but, not actually waiting for it to finish. You have to actually use the await keyword on a Promise value.  This is really obvious when you look at how long it takes your code to execute. It should take about 5 seconds but it completes instantly.

Comment: Ah! I forgot to return the promise. Thanks Deadron! At least now I know my 'theory' on how to write this code should work.